# Hiding/showing a fragment that's inside a bottom-sheet sets the bottom-sheet's state to expanded

Tags: java, android, fragment, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to make a fragment that's inside a bottom-sheet hide when the state is changed to collapsed.

The problem is that when it hides the bottom-sheet expands.

How can I make it disappear without expanding the bottom-sheet?

```
behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if(newState==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
                    if(fragmentTransaction!=null)
                    {
                        fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment).commit();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below

```
if(newState==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){            
     behavior.setHideable = true
     behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
}
```

Comment: I still want to be able to expand the bottom-sheet